# Close "This PC" using command line or Powershell on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, shutdown

If I type in "explorer" in powershell, it opens "This PC".  How can I close "This PC" using command line or powershell script?

Comment: When I do Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} | Select-Object MainWindowTitle, ID, it will show "This PC" sometimes, but not all the time.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish by starting 'explorer.exe' via PowerShell with no starting location?

What OS are you running? On Win10 this opens at 'Quick Access'.

You can use PowerShell to open explorer to any directory you choose using

```
Invoke-Item -path SomeQuaifiedPath

# or 

ii SomeQualifiedPath
```

You can get the main window name of a given process, of course along with its Id and stop them by either property, using the Stop-Process cmdlet.

```
Get-Process | 
Where-Object -FilterScript {
    $PSItem.MainWindowHandle -ne 0 
} |
Select-Object -Property Name, Description, MainWindowTitle, Company, ID |
Out-GridView -Title 'Choose Application to Kill' -PassThru | 
Stop-Process -Force -Confirm:$true
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
Start-Process Explorer
$explorerID = (Get-Process Explorer).Id
Stop-Process -Id $explorerID
```